# Cursor movement won't happen without a fmt.Print()

Tags: go

Basically I'm making a Go IDE from scratch. One thing I came across while trying to make the cursor move around the screen was it wouldn't work if I didn't have a random fmt.Print(string(buffer)) in place.

I managed to hack it in so it doesn't break the implementation further down the line. I have tried just showing a single slice, part of the slice, but no, it requires the whole thing converted to string.

https://gitlab.com/snippets/1891919
EDIT: wrong link

snippetted because the formatting is wonky.

That allows you to walk the cursor around, however if you take out the fmt.Printf(string(buffer)) it won't let you move around at all.

Comment: cleaned up the code so it should work with a few minor imports

Comment: I suggest to use something similar to https://github.com/buger/goterm. You cannot write an IDE with Printf, you need low-level terminal operations.

Comment: Thanks but no thanks. Just wondering what is going on in a lower level here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press the arrow keys, they are printing escape sequences to STDIN. You are capturing those escape sequences, checking what they are, then printing them back out so the movement can be interpreted by your terminal. When you take out the print statements, your terminal never receives the escape codes, so it doesn't know to move the cursor.

Instead of just passing what you get from STDIN, you could write your own library that prints the escape sequences and make calls to that instead.